# ArrayBuffer to base64 encoded string

Tags: javascript, encoding, base64, arraybuffer

I need an efficient (read native) way to convert an `ArrayBuffer` to a base64 string which needs to be used on a multipart post.

Comment: if you need it in a multipart/form-data then create a `FormData` and a `Blob` from ArrayBuffer, append the blob to formdata and post binary data instead of base64.

Answer (score 352):

```
function _arrayBufferToBase64( buffer ) {
    var binary = '';
    var bytes = new Uint8Array( buffer );
    var len = bytes.byteLength;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        binary += String.fromCharCode( bytes[ i ] );
    }
    return window.btoa( binary );
}
```

but, non-native implementations are faster e.g. https://gist.github.com/958841
see http://jsperf.com/encoding-xhr-image-data/6

Updated benchmarks: https://jsben.ch/wnaZC

Comment: I tried the non-native implementation from the link and it took 1min and half to convert a 1M size buffer while the loop code above only took 1sec.

Comment: I like the simplicity of this approach, but all that string concatenation can be costly. It looks like building an array of the characters and `join()`ing them at the end is significantly faster on Firefox, IE, and Safari (but quite a lot slower on Chrome): http://jsperf.com/tobase64-implementations

Comment: I am using this function for array buffer to base64 conversion but I am not able to get back the array buffer. I have wrriten a _base64ToArrayBuffer() function here: http://codeshare.io/PT4pb but that gives me an error as: `Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window': The string to be decoded is not correctly encoded.`

Comment: this is not worked this JSZip. i find another way https://github.com/michael/github/issues/137

Comment: I am trying 50mb pdf file upload using angualrjs and webapi2. I am using above line code , after upload file, the page got crashed and hanged .

Below line of code ,I was used but getting null value in webapi method.
"var base64String = btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer)));"

please suggest any idea ...

Comment: This is not binary safe. Does anyone know about a binary safe option?

Comment: Not safe. See @chemoish answer

Comment: Unfortunately won't work in node.js. Because of node.js' Utf-8 string encoding `String.fromCharCode()` behave different for byte values >= 0x80.

Comment: @bawejakunal Seems to work find for me: https://jsfiddle.net/5cf7bpdu/    Open devtools console and you'll see it's working.

Comment: I'm wondering why everyone is avoiding the native buffer `toString('base64')` method.

Comment: @JoãoEduardoSoareseSilva because not everyone is using Node - Node's `Buffer` doesn't exist in the browser.

Comment: @Andrew After I got better context to this question I learned that, I provided my own answer for Node users on this question, the issue is that this question is so popular that it overshadows the results for people that are using Node.

Comment: I tried with "_arrayBufferToBase64" method and first time its uploading fine for 600MB and again i tried to upload 150MB file, browser is throwing "out of memory" page. Please let me now how can we avoid this or is there any limit to size or above method is storing in browser cache.

Comment: Hello from 2022 in Firefox. So it seems like Alex and @cuixiping's solutions are the fastest and most preferred as of 2022?

Comment: btoa converts array to string before converting it to base64

Answer (score 191):

This works fine for me:

```
var base64String = btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer)));
```

In ES6, the syntax is a little simpler:

```
const base64String = btoa(String.fromCharCode(...new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer)));
```

As pointed out in the comments, this method may result in a runtime error in some browsers when the `ArrayBuffer` is large. The exact size limit is implementation dependent in any case.

Comment: I like this method better for conciseness, but get a "maximum call stack size exceeded error". The loop technique above gets around that.

Comment: I'm also getting a stack size error, so I used mobz's answer and it worked great.

Comment: It didn't work for large buffers. Slight modification to make it work: `btoa([].reduce.call(new Uint8Array(bufferArray),function(p,c){return p+String.fromCharCode(c)},''))`

Comment: I am trying 50mb pdf file upload using angualrjs and webapi2. I am using above line code , after upload file, the page got crashed and hanged . Below line of code ,I was used but getting null value in webapi method. "var base64String = btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer)));" please suggest any idea ...

Comment: could you add the ultimate markup/image string to your answer as well by any chance?
I have BMP images stored in SQL that I'm trying to display but this code isn't working:

'data:image/bmp;base64,' + btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer)));

Comment: @BelgoCanadian I don't see what's wrong with that expression. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207190/embedding-base64-images) for your question. If this doesn't help then you should ask a new question and provide some more information.

Comment: Not safe. See @chemoish answer

Comment: @Kugel `btoa` is safe for characters in the code range 0-255, as this is here the case (Think about the 8 in `Uint8Array`).

Comment: how do you reverse this back to bytes array?

Comment: FWIW, on Chrome 104 using `...` is much slower than using `apply`.

Comment: a very good answer in many cases (small buffers like crypto keys, signatures...)

Answer (score 60):

For those who like it short, here's an other one using `Array.reduce` which will not cause stack overflow:

```
var base64 = btoa(
  new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer)
    .reduce((data, byte) => data + String.fromCharCode(byte), '')
);
```

Comment: Not sure if that's really sexy. After all, you're creating `<amount of Bytes in the buffer>` new strings.

Comment: How about `btoa(new Uint8Array(arraybuffer).reduce((data,byte)=>(data.push(String.fromCharCode(byte)),data),[]).join(''))`?

Comment: Another alternative: `btoa(Array.from(new Uint8Array(arraybuffer)).map(b => String.fromCharCode(b)).join(''))`.

Comment: Failed to execute 'btoa' on 'Window': The string to be encoded contains characters outside of the Latin1 range

Answer (score 48):

The OP did not specify the Running Environment, but if you are using Node.JS there is a very simple way to do this.

According to the official Node.JS docs:
https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffers_and_character_encodings

```
// This step is only necessary if you don't already have a Buffer Object
const buffer = Buffer.from(yourArrayBuffer);

const base64String = buffer.toString('base64');
```

Also, if you are running under Angular for example, the `Buffer` class will also be made available in a browser environment.

Comment: Your answer only applies to NodeJS and will not work in the browser.

Comment: @jvatic I see, the OP did not clearly specify the Running Environment, so my answer is not incorrect, he only tagged `Javascript`. So I updated my answer to make it more concise. I think this is an important answer because I was searching how to do this and could not get to the best answer to the problem.

Comment: I came to realize recently that the Question date precedes NodeJS itself, which is more reason that the Mods should add an addendum to the question, because these days most people are looking for a solution on nodeJS and get mislead by the popularity of the old answers.

Answer (score 45):

There is another asynchronous way use Blob and FileReader.

I didn't test the performance. But it is a different way of thinking.

```
function arrayBufferToBase64( buffer, callback ) {
    var blob = new Blob([buffer],{type:'application/octet-binary'});
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(evt){
        var dataurl = evt.target.result;
        callback(dataurl.substr(dataurl.indexOf(',')+1));
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
}

//example:
var buf = new Uint8Array([11,22,33]);
arrayBufferToBase64(buf, console.log.bind(console)); //"CxYh"
```

Comment: Use `dataurl.split(',', 2)[1]`instead of `dataurl.substr(dataurl.indexOf(',')+1)`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be guaranteed to work. According to https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#issue-f80bda5b `readAsDataURL` could theoretically return a percent encoded dataURI (And it seems it is actually the case in [jsdom](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/2269))

Comment: @CarterMedlin Why would `split` be better than `substring`?

Comment: split is shorter. but dataurl may contains one or more commas(,), split is not safe.

Comment: Additional note on the warning @TS gave: NodeJS is the engine which, for certain inputs, will return percent-encoded strings rather than base64. So as long as your code is running only in browsers, it appears the method above will always return a base64-encoded string, currently. (although the linked issue shows that the W3C spec does not guarantee this as of now)

Answer (score 38):

This example uses the built-in [FileReader readDataURL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL) to do the conversion to base64 encoding. [Data URLs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URLs) are structured `data:[<mediatype>][;base64],<data>`, so we split that url at the comma and return only the base64 encoded characters.

```
const blob = new Blob([array]);        
const reader = new FileReader();

reader.onload = (event) => {
  const dataUrl = event.target.result;
  const [_, base64] = dataUrl.split(','); 
  // do something with base64
};
   
reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
```

Or as a promisified utility:

```
async function encode(array) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    const blob = new Blob([array]);
    const reader = new FileReader();
    
    reader.onload = (event) => {
      const dataUrl = event.target.result;
      const [_, base64] = dataUrl.split(',');
      
      resolve(base64);
    };
    
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
  });
}

const encoded = await encode(typedArray);
```

Comment: Add some explanation to your answer please. What does this code mean?

Comment: Similar [helpful MDN example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob#Extracting_data_from_a_Blob).

Comment: this is by far the fastest approach - tens of times faster than the other ones in my limited testing

Comment: i wish i'd found this solution like 8 hours again. my day would not have been wasted ;( thank you

Comment: I think you also need to remove the DataURL header (`data:*/*;base64,`) to obtain just the Base64 string. See [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL)

Comment: How do you convert the base64 back to the array (after using this method to encode to base64) ?

Comment: Ah, may have found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54123275/2030549

Answer (score 26):

I used this and works for me.

```
function arrayBufferToBase64( buffer ) {
    var binary = '';
    var bytes = new Uint8Array( buffer );
    var len = bytes.byteLength;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        binary += String.fromCharCode( bytes[ i ] );
    }
    return window.btoa( binary );
}



function base64ToArrayBuffer(base64) {
    var binary_string =  window.atob(base64);
    var len = binary_string.length;
    var bytes = new Uint8Array( len );
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)        {
        bytes[i] = binary_string.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return bytes.buffer;
}
```

Comment: Not safe. See @chemoish answer

Comment: This is the only solution i have found that worked for me.

Comment: This is the most readable solution.

Answer (score 18):

My recommendation for this is to NOT use native `btoa` strategies—as they don't correctly encode all `ArrayBuffer`'s…

[rewrite the DOMs atob() and btoa()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding#Solution_2_%E2%80%93_rewrite_the_DOMs_atob()_and_btoa()_using_JavaScript's_TypedArrays_and_UTF-8)

> Since DOMStrings are 16-bit-encoded strings, in most browsers calling window.btoa on a Unicode string will cause a Character Out Of Range exception if a character exceeds the range of a 8-bit ASCII-encoded character.

While I have never encountered this exact error, I have found that many of the `ArrayBuffer`'s I have tried to encode have encoded incorrectly.

I would either use MDN recommendation or gist.

- https://github.com/beatgammit/base64-js
- https://gist.github.com/jonleighton/958841

Comment: `btoa` not works on String, but OP is asking `ArrayBuffer`.

Comment: Very much this, so many snippets here that recommend the wrong thing! I've seen this error multiple times, where people blindly use atob and btoa.

Comment: All array buffers should be encoded fine using the strategies in other answers, atob/btoa is only a problem for text that contains characters greater than 0xFF (which byte arrays by definition do not).

The MDN warning doesn't apply because when using the strategy in the other answers you are guaranteed to have a string that only consists of ASCII characters as any value from a Uint8Array is guaranteed to be between 0 and 255 which means String.fromCharCode is guaranteed to return a character that is not out of range.

Comment: This is the correct answer when btoa or Buffer are not available (react-native)

Answer (score 16):

Below are 2 simple functions for converting Uint8Array to Base64 String and back again

```
arrayToBase64String(a) {
    return btoa(String.fromCharCode(...a));
}

base64StringToArray(s) {
    let asciiString = atob(s);
    return new Uint8Array([...asciiString].map(char => char.charCodeAt(0)));
}
```

Comment: This is a confusing answer.  That does not look look like valid JavaScript and is a Uint8Array an ArrayBuffer?

Comment: @user1153660 Add the `function` keyword and it should work in a modern browser.

Comment: Awesome! btoa(String.fromCharCode(...a)); is shortest version I have seen so far to encode Uint8Array.

Comment: This looks good but if the array is too huge it will throw maximum call stack size exceeded error.

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me:

```js
Buffer.from(myArrayBuffer).toString("base64");
```

Comment: Is this specific to NodeJS, and does it perform a copy in the `from` method?

Comment: idk, do you have the answer?

Comment: If I knew the answer I would not have asked, I'd have improved your answer instead :)

Answer (score 5):

If you're okay with adding a library, [base64-arraybuffer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/base64-arraybuffer):

```sh
yarn add base64-arraybuffer
```

then:

- `encode(buffer)` - Encodes ArrayBuffer into base64 string
- `decode(str)` - Decodes base64 string to ArrayBuffer

Comment: best answer for me since includes the decoding

Answer (score 1):

```
ABtoB64(ab) {
    return new Promise(res => {
        const fr = new FileReader();
        fr.onload = ({target: {result: s}}) => res(s.slice(s.indexOf(';base64,') + 8));
        fr.readAsDataURL(new Blob([ab]));
    });
}
```

asynchronous method using file reader.

Answer (score 1):

In the Browser suggested solutions with `btoa` seem fine.
But in Node.js [btoa is Legacy](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/buffer.html#bufferbtoadata)

It is recommended to use `buffer.toString(encoding)`

like

`const myString = buffer.toString("base64")`

Answer (score 1):

i use `TextDecode` api to convert it to normal text and then convert it to Base64

```js
const uint =  new Uint8Array([ 73, 32, 108, 111, 118, 101, 32, 121, 111, 117 ]).buffer
const decoder = new TextDecoder()
const decodedText = decoder.decode(uint)
const base64Code = btoa(decodedText)
```

Comment: Works great! One-line version: `btoa(new TextDecoder().decode(myUint8Array))` Don't know why this isn't rated higher; it's just like [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11562550) that uses `String.fromCharCode(...myUint8Array)`, except without the stack-overflow concern (afaik).

Comment: Ah, I perhaps see why some don't prefer this route: `TextDecoder` works for characters 0-127 (those in the `Latin1` set), but errors for array values between 128-255. So [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11562550) does have wider compatibility, if you think you may encounter array-values outside the 0-127 (`Latin1`) range. (actually, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38858127) is maybe better since avoids the stack-overflow issue that the other can hit; or perhaps [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38291093), though has negative of being async)

Answer (score 0):

You can derive a normal array from the `ArrayBuffer` by using `Array.prototype.slice`. 
Use a function like `Array.prototype.map` to convert bytes in to characters and `join` them together to forma  string.

```
function arrayBufferToBase64(ab){

    var dView = new Uint8Array(ab);   //Get a byte view        

    var arr = Array.prototype.slice.call(dView); //Create a normal array        

    var arr1 = arr.map(function(item){        
      return String.fromCharCode(item);    //Convert
    });

    return window.btoa(arr1.join(''));   //Form a string

}
```

This method is faster since there are no string concatenations running in it.

Comment: Not safe. See @chemoish answer

Answer (score 0):

```
 var uint8Array = new Uint8Array(BytesArray);

 var base64Str = btoa(String.fromCharCode(...uint8Array));

 Or,

 var base64Str = btoa(uint8Array.reduce((x, y) => x + String.fromCharCode(y), ''));
```

Answer (score -1):

Use [`uint8-to-b64`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uint8-to-b64) package to do encoding/decoding in browser and Node.js

Answer (score -4):

By my side, using Chrome navigator, I had to use DataView() to read an arrayBuffer

```
function _arrayBufferToBase64( tabU8A ) {
var binary = '';
let lecteur_de_donnees = new DataView(tabU8A);
var len = lecteur_de_donnees.byteLength;
var chaine = '';
var pos1;
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    binary += String.fromCharCode( lecteur_de_donnees.getUint8( i ) );
}
chaine = window.btoa( binary )
return chaine;}
```

Answer (score -6):

```
function _arrayBufferToBase64(uarr) {
    var strings = [], chunksize = 0xffff;
    var len = uarr.length;

    for (var i = 0; i * chunksize < len; i++){
        strings.push(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, uarr.subarray(i * chunksize, (i + 1) * chunksize)));
    }

    return strings.join("");
}
```

This is better, if you use JSZip for unpack archive from string