# Alternative to readAsBinaryString for IE10

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-10, filereader

It seems that [readAsBinaryString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader#readAsBinaryString%28%29), a method of the JavaScript `FileReader` object, is not supported in IE10. I've tried the following, as suggested in [this HTML5 Rocks article](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/06/How-to-convert-ArrayBuffer-to-and-from-String):

```
String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint16Array(buffer));
```

However, this results in an `Out of stack space` error.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9267899/arraybuffer-to-base64-encoded-string):

```
var binary = "";
var bytes = new Uint8Array(buffer);
var length = bytes.byteLength;
for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  binary += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, David. I tried typing this in code and got an error, `ReferenceError: UInt8Array is not defined`. After a moment I realized the type is counter-intuitively named `Uint8Array` instead of `UInt8Array` - note the lower case "i". Bad developer! So sad!

Answer (score 3):

From the David Jones's answer, I wrote this method. The try/catch handles the readAsBinaryString exception in IE10/11 and call itself the "IE mode":

```
function readBinaryStringFromBlob(blob, callback, ie) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    if(!ie) {
        reader.addEventListener("loadend", function () {
            callback(reader.result);
        });
        try {
            reader.readAsBinaryString(blob);
        } catch (err) {
            readBinaryStringFromBlob(blob, callback, true);
        }
    } else {
        reader.addEventListener("loadend", function () {
            var binary = "";
            var bytes = new Uint8Array(reader.result);
            var length = bytes.byteLength;
            for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                binary += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);
            }
            callback(binary);
        });
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like something a little terser and ES2015-ier then this may be what you're after:

```
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onerror = e => alert("File cannot be opened");

  if (reader.readAsBinaryString) {
     reader.onload = e => alert(e.target.result));
     reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
  }
  else {
     // Catering for IE 10/11
     reader.onload = e => {
        const bytes = new Uint8Array(e.target.result);
        const binary = bytes.reduce((acc, byte) => acc + String.fromCharCode(byte), "");
        alert(binary);
     };
     reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try my code:

```
    function readAsBinaryString(blob, callback) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        var binStringCallback = function (e) {
            callback(e.target.result);
        };

        var arrBufferCallback = function (e) {
            var binary = "";
            var bytes = new Uint8Array(e.target.result);
            var length = bytes.byteLength;
            for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                binary += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);
            }
            callback(binary);
        };

        reader.onerror = reader.onabort = function () {
            callback(null)
        };

        if (typeof reader.readAsBinaryString != "undefined") {
            reader.onload = binStringCallback;
            reader.readAsBinaryString(blob);
        } else {
            reader.onload = arrBufferCallback;
            reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
        }
    }
```