# Javascript Reader.readAsBinaryString doesnt work in IE

Tags: javascript, filereader

Can someone help me out! my `reader.readAsBinaryString()` doesn't work in IE.

Now I find some other ways online but I'm not able to get this working.
Can someone help me transform my method so it will work?

```
 function uploadFile(){        
    var accountId = document.getElementById('accountId').value;
    var folderId = document.getElementById('folderId').value;
    var input = document.getElementById('file-input');

    var filesToUpload = input.files;
    
    if(filesToUpload[0] == 'undefined' || filesToUpload[0] == null){
        showMessage('File Not Found!','WARNING');
        return;
    }
    
    ///Get Account to later update the account logo id
    var queryAcc = "SELECT Id, Account_Logo_Id__c FROM Account WHERE Id = '{!getAccountId}' limit 1"; 
    var resultAcc = sforce.connection.query(queryAcc); 
    var recordsAcc = resultAcc.getArray("records");         
    var account = recordsAcc[0];
    
    ///Get existing document if exist
    var docName = 'accLogo_' + accountId;
    var queryDoc = "SELECT Id FROM Document WHERE Name = '"+ docName +"' limit 1";         
    var resultDoc = sforce.connection.query(queryDoc);
    var recordsDoc = resultDoc.getArray("records");
    var existingDocument = recordsDoc[0];
    
    for(var i = 0, f; f = filesToUpload[i]; i++){
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.file = f;

        reader.onerror = function(e){
            switch(e.target.error.code){
                case e.target.error.NOT_FOUND_ERR:
                    showMessage('File Not Found!','WARNING');
                    break;
                case e.target.error.NOT_READABLE_ERR:
                    showMessage('File is not readable','WARNING');
                    break;
                case e.target.error.ABORT_ERR:
                    break; 
                default:
                    showMessage('An error occurred reading this file.','WARNING');
            };
        };     

        reader.onabort = function(e){
            showMessage('File read cancelled','WARNING');
        };

        reader.onload = function(e){
            if(existingDocument == 'undefined' || existingDocument == null){
                var doc = new sforce.SObject("Document");
                doc.Name = 'accLogo_' + accountId ;
                doc.Type = '.jpg';
                doc.Description = 'Account Logo for account:' + accountId ;
                doc.FolderId = folderId;
                doc.Body = (new sforce.Base64Binary(e.target.result)).toString();

                sforce.connection.create([doc],
                {
                    onSuccess : function(result, source) 
                    {
                        if (result[0].getBoolean("success")) 
                        {
                            console.log("new document created with id " + result[0].id);
                            account.Account_Logo_Id__c = result[0].id;
                            var results = sforce.connection.update([account]);
                            showMessage('Logo uploaded succesfull', 'SUCCESS');
                        } 
                        else 
                        {
                            console.log("failed to create document " + result[0]);
                            showMessage('Insert failed: ' + result[0], 'ERROR');
                        }
                    }, 
                    onFailure : function(error, source) 
                    {
                    console.log("An error has occurred " + error);
                    showMessage('Insert failed: ' + error, 'ERROR');
                    }
                });
            }else{
                existingDocument.Body = (new sforce.Base64Binary(e.target.result)).toString();

                sforce.connection.update([existingDocument],
                {
                    onSuccess : function(result, source) 
                    {
                        if (result[0].getBoolean("success")) 
                        {
                            console.log("new document updated with id " + result[0].id);
                            account.Account_Logo_Id__c = result[0].id;
                            var results = sforce.connection.update([account]);
                            showMessage('Logo uploaded succesfull', 'SUCCESS');
                        } 
                        else 
                        {
                            console.log("failed to update document " + result[0]);
                            showMessage('Update failed: ' + result[0], 'ERROR');
                        }
                    }, 
                    onFailure : function(error, source) 
                    {
                    console.log("An error has occurred " + error);
                    showMessage('Update failed: ' + error, 'ERROR');
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        reader.readAsBinaryString(f);
    }
}
```

Comment: see [MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsBinaryString) - `readAsBinaryString` is not a standard, but only IE doesn't support it

Comment: [The link contains fallback for IE.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18582643/alternative-to-readasbinarystring-for-ie10)

Comment: in fact, readAsBinaryString is deprecated, so don't use it  - you should use `readAsArrayBuffer`