# Angular : show image from REST Service

Tags: angularjs, image, rest, binary, base64

After reseaches and tests, I still can't show an image form ReST API on my Angular App. I have images available on my ReST web service, why do I use a ReST service? Because in order to access you need to be authenticated (I use oAuth 2 protocol). When I use POSTMan (ReST client very usefull) everything works great, the image is displayed without doing nothing. But when I try to display it with Angular after a $http it doesn't work.

Here are the headers received form the service :

```
Content-Length → 51756
Content-Type → image/jpeg; charset=binary
Server → Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12
X-Powered-By → PHP/5.5.12
```

Here is my Angular code :

```
var data64 = $base64.encode(unescape(encodeURIComponent(data)));
scope.src = 'data:image/jpeg;charset=binary;base64,' + data64;
```

and my HTML :

```
<img ng-src="{{src}}" border="0" />
```

For information I use angular-base64 (https://github.com/ninjatronic/angular-base64) for the encodage. Without "unescape" and "encodeURIComponent" I have an error, I've tried to remove white spaces but it still doesn't work.

Thank you :)

Comment: why don't you directly put the REST-URL into ng-src?

Comment: hello, because I need to add header, like I said I use an OAuth protocol, so I need to add some headers and a token...

Comment: got it. Your header says it is a `image/jpeg` but your data string starts with `ìmage/png`. And why do you include the `charset=binary`?

Comment: Sorry I've forgot to change  png to jpeg before copying, but it still doesn't work even if I remove the charset=binary...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that this will not work since you tell the browser that the image data is base64 encoded, but you also transformed it with `unescape` and `encodeURIComponent`.

Why don't you fetch your image data into a binary data structure (requires a modern browser), instead of into a string:

```
$http.get(req, {responseType: "arraybuffer"}).
    success(function(data) {
        $scope.src = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + _arrayBufferToBase64(data);
    });
```

`_arrayBufferToBase64` is defined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9267899/arraybuffer-to-base64-encoded-string).

---

A different approach would be to install a request interceptor, recognize the image url and add the oauth headers for this case.

Comment: Nice ! :) It work for me. I'll test browsers for compatibility (It works on Chrome)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I tryed this way in angular 8+ and works fine:

```
imageToShow: any;
createImageFromBlob(image: Blob) {
let reader = new FileReader();
reader.addEventListener("load", () => {
  this.imageToShow = reader.result;
}, false);
if (image) {
  reader.readAsDataURL(image);
}
}
```

and also call it like this:

```
getImageFromService() {
  this.api.getImage(key).subscribe(data => {
    this.createImageFromBlob(data);    
  }, error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
 }
```