# Get Blob from Blob.text()

Tags: javascript, typescript, blob, data-conversion

I have a save image function that looks like this:

```js
async saveImage(image: Blob, key: string) {
    // using: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/text
    const content = await image.text();
    window.localStorage.setItem(key, content);
}
```

Now I like to create a load Image function looking like this:

```js
async loadImage(key: string) : Blob {
    const item = window.localStorage.getItem(key);
    const imageBlob = ???
    return imageBlob;
}
```

How can I convert the [USVString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/USVString) that was generated by `Blob.text()` back to a `new Blob()`?

Comment: The [`Blob` constructor takes a `USVString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/Blob)....  Note that saving an actual image file like PNG or JPEG as text isn't going to work, since `text()`, as the linked page notes, outputs the bytes interpreted as UTF-8 encoded characters. The bytes in an image do not stay within those parameters.

Comment: See [Save a File Image to localstorage HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31850732/215552) for instructions on how to do what you want to do.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Works perfectly. If you put your comments in an answer I'm happy to close this question :)

Comment: Found an even better solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245767/creating-a-blob-from-a-base64-string-in-javascript

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating a BLOB from a Base64 string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245767/creating-a-blob-from-a-base64-string-in-javascript)