# Reading Blobs in IE11

Tags: javascript, csv, blob, internet-explorer-11, filereader

I used [this](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/) article to read a CSV file using JavaScript. The code below works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but IE 11 throws the following error:

```
Object doesn't support property or method 'readAsBinaryString'
```

when calling:

```
reader.readAsBinaryString(blob);
```

According to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh772310(v=vs.85).aspx) MSDN article, however, `readAsBinaryString` is a method supported by `FileReader`. Am I missing something / is there a different way of reading files in IE 11?

HTML code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Import CSV File</td>
        <td><input type="file" id="files" name="file"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>       
<button id="read" href="#">Read</button>
```

JS code:

```
//read a file
function readBlob() {

var files = document.getElementById('files').files;

if (!files.length) {
    alert('Please select a file!');
    return;
}

var file = files[0];
var start = 0;
var stop = file.size - 1;
var reader = new FileReader();

// If we use onloadend, we need to check the readyState.
reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
    if (evt.target.readyState == FileReader.DONE) { // DONE == 2
        makeJSON(evt.target.result);
    }
};

var blob = file.slice(start, stop + 1);
reader.readAsBinaryString(blob);
```

}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`FileReader` also supports `readAsText` method, which can be used to read a File or Blob object into memory as a text string across all three browsers (Chrome, FF, and IE11).

Replacing `reader.readAsBinaryString(blob)` with `reader.readAsText(blob)` fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use this:

```
var binary = "";
var bytes = new Uint8Array(buffer);
var length = bytes.byteLength;
for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  binary += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);
}
```

Reference : [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9267899/arraybuffer-to-base64-encoded-string)