# Image from Byte Array does not show with Angular

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to display an image from byte array using Angularjs.  I have tried each of the solutions I've found on the web, but none of them are working.

Currently, in my HTML, I have:

```
        <img ng-src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{{company.imgCompanyLogo}}" />
```

My controller code is:

```
angular.module('myModule').controller('ContractorCtrl', function ($scope, contractorService, $interval, $window) {

    getcontractorInfo();
    function getcontractorInfo() {
        contractorService.getContractorInfo()
        .success(function (data) {
            $scope.company = data;
        });
    };
```

Everything I've read says what I am doing should work.  All the data retrieved displays except for the picture, and I'm sure the name of the field "imgCompanyLogo" is correct. What am I missing?

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: can you do a `console.log(data.imgCompanyLogo)` to verify? Also, going off your title, `company.imgCompanyLogo` should be a base64 string, not a byte array.

Comment: It gives me a Failed:data:image/jpeg;base64,[255,216,255,224,0,16,74,70,73,70,0,1,1,1,0,31,0,31,…,40,162,138,0,40,162,138,0,40,162,138,0,40,162,138,0,40,162,138,0,255,217] Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INVALID_URL

Comment: That's not base64 data.

Comment: from what I understand it is a "byte" array.  Any ideas?

Comment: you need to convert your byte array to a base64 string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert the array to a base64-encoded string. [This question has information on converting it: ArrayBuffer to base64 encoded string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9267899/arraybuffer-to-base64-encoded-string).

With [mobz answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9458996/548083), you can add the function into the scope:

```
$scope.arrayBufferToBase64 = function( buffer ) {
    var binary = '';
    var bytes = new Uint8Array( buffer );
    var len = bytes.byteLength;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        binary += String.fromCharCode( bytes[ i ] );
    }
    return window.btoa( binary );
}
```

From there, you can just do:

```
<img ng-src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{{arrayBufferToBase64(company.imgCompanyLogo)}}" />
```

It'll probably be pretty slow FYI. If you can, you might be able to leverage canvas to improve performance.

Answer (score 0):

Make it a filter so that you can use it simple
Like

```
app.filter('bytetobase', function () {
    return function (buffer) {
        var binary = '';
        var bytes = new Uint8Array(buffer);
        var len = bytes.byteLength;
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            binary += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);
        }
        return window.btoa(binary);
    };
});
```

And just call the filter in you img tag as

```
<img ng-src="data:image/JPEG;base64,{{picture | bytetobase}}" alt="..." width="100" height="100">
```