# How to convert bytes[] to base64 to show image in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, base64

I am getting a bytes array from ajax call and now i want to convert it to image. I have searched it and i find a way to convert bytes array into base64.My question is how i convert bytes array into base64 in java script or is there any way to show image through bytes array?

```
$.ajax({
            url: urlGetImages,
            data: { id: id },
            type: 'GET',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

            success: function (data) {

                debugger;
                totalImages = data.AdditionalData.ImagesByteses.length;
                if (totalImages > 0) {

                    //data.AdditionalData.ImagesByteses[0] is array of bytes
                    var imagemarkup ="<img src"">" // I want to show image from this byte array



                }



            },
            error: function () {
                alert(error);
            }
        });
```

Comment: show your code please.

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: This below link might help you :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9267899/arraybuffer-to-base64-encoded-string

Comment: @Hiba thanks, but we still don't see how the byte-array is created.

Comment: I get bytes array from server side

Comment: Your img tag should be something like: <img src="data:image/png;base64,blablabla..." />, where blablabla is the image data in Base64 encoding

Comment: Not it is in bytes array

Comment: I convert using this:var base64Sstring = new ArrayBuffer(storedImageBytes).toString('base64');

Comment: @Hiba all data on a computer is made out of bytes, so "byte array" is a very vague expression. for example a string can also be represented as a byte array (like a char array in C). or every byte in your array could represent a character. after that we still don't know which compression/encoding your image data is representing. is it a JPG, PNG, GIF... ?