# Getting MD5 hash in JavaScript and converting it to base 64

Tags: javascript, api, base64, md5

I’d like to use a set of REST API through JavaScript and I’m reading the documentation explaining how to implement authentication.
The following instructions are illustrated in pseudocode but I have some issue on understanding how to implement it in JavaScript (my JS level is quite basic).
This is the unclear part:

```
= FromBytesToBase64String(MD5Hash("{\n    \"data\": {\n        \"type\": \"company\",\n        \"id\": \"879f2dfc-57ea-4dbb-96c7-c546f8812f1e\",\n        \"external_1_value\": \"Updated value\"\n    }\n}"))
```

Basically I should calculate MD5 hash of the string in question and then I should encode it in base  64 string If I understood well.

The documentation shows the flow broken in sub-steps:

= FromBytesToBase64String(b'eC\xcda\xa3\xa7\xaf\xa53\x93\xb4.\xa2\xb1\xe3]')

And then the final result:

"ZUPNYaOnr6Uzk7QuorHjXQ=="

I tried to do the same by using crypto.js library  and I get a MD5 hash string but then how can I get this value "ZUPNYaOnr6Uzk7QuorHjXQ==" ?
Any idea on how I could do it?

Thanks so much for helping!

Answer (score 0):

That final result is the base64 encoded string.  The function `FromBytesToBase64String` is what produces it, but this is not a standard function in JavaScript.

Instead, try using one of the built-in functions documented [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding).  Specifically:

```
window.btoa(MD5Hash("Your input string"));
```

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for your answer, I tried as you said only thing the string I get is this one: NjU0M2NkNjFhM2E3YWZhNTMzOTNiNDJlYTJiMWUzNWQ=  which doesn't correspond to the final value I should get according to API documentation which should be ZUPNYaOnr6Uzk7QuorHjXQ==   any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

window.btoa(MD5Hash("Your input string")); does not work because btoa takes the md5 string and converts that character by character, hence you need to feed it an byte array.I ended up combining [ArrayBuffer to base64 encoded string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9267899/arraybuffer-to-base64-encoded-string) 
with https://github.com/pvorb/node-md5/issues/25

into :

```
function md5ToBase64(md5String,boolTrimLast){
    var strRet = arrayBufferToBase64(hexByteStringToByteArray(md5String));
    return boolTrimLast?strRet.slice(0,22):strRet;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

use the [btoa()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_btoa.asp) function to get a base64 encoded string.

Answer (score -1):

Use [WindowBase64.btoa()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/btoa):

```
var encodedData = window.btoa(md5Hash);
```