# Text to an Array Buffer causes files to be corrupted

Tags: javascript, html, filereader

I have a sample, from it the user can select a file (PDF files in particular), convert that file to an array buffer, construct the file back from that array buffer and download that file. works as expected.

```
<input type="file" id="file_input" class="foo" />
<div id="output_field" class="foo"></div>


$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#file_input').on('change', function(e){
        readFile(this.files[0], function(e) {
            //manipulate with result...
            $('#output_field').text(e.target.result);
            try {           
            var file = new Blob([e.target.result], { type: 'application/pdf' });
            var fileURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
            var seconds = new Date().getTime() / 1000;
            var fileName = "cert" + parseInt(seconds) + ".pdf";
            var a = document.createElement("a");
            document.body.appendChild(a);
            a.style = "display: none";
            a.href = fileURL;
            a.download = fileName;
            a.click();
             }
            catch (err){
            $('#output_field').text(err);
            }
        });     
    });
});

function readFile(file, callback){
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = callback
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
}
```

Now let's say I used  `reader.readAsText(file);` isntead of `reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);`. In that case I would convert the text to an array buffer and try to do that same thing.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#file_input').on('change', function(e){
        readFile(this.files[0], function(e) {
            //manipulate with result...
            try {
            var buf = new ArrayBuffer(e.target.result.length * 2); 
            var bufView = new Uint16Array(buf);
            for (var i=0, strLen = e.target.result.length; i<strLen; i++) {
                     bufView[i] = e.target.result.charCodeAt(i);
            }

            var file = new Blob([bufView], { type: 'application/pdf' });
            var fileURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
            var seconds = new Date().getTime() / 1000;
            var fileName = "cert" + parseInt(seconds) + ".pdf";
            var a = document.createElement("a");
            document.body.appendChild(a);
            a.style = "display: none";
            a.href = fileURL;
            a.download = fileName;
            a.click();
             }
            catch (err){
            $('#output_field').text(err);
            }
        });

    });
});

function readFile(file, callback){
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = callback
    reader.readAsText(file);
}
```

Now if I passed a PDF file that is small in size and only has text, this would work file, but when selecting files that are large and/or has images in them, a currputed file will be downloaded.

Now I do know that I'm trying to make life harder for myself. But what I'm trying to do is somehow convert the result from `readAsText()` into an arrayBuffer so that both of `readAsText()` and `readAsArrayBuffer()` work identicaly.

Comment: Is there any reason for you to actually use `readAsText`? As I understand, readAsArrayBuffer is working fine, no? It might very well be that readAsText looses some information in bytes that can't be interpreted as text

Comment: it's because in my particular case, I'm dealing with a backend server that returns files in this format, and I can't change anything about it. this example was just to demonstrate my case and hopefully find a solution to it

Comment: Can you post the file that you are trying with and the result you got, or at least the difference (using a hex editor)?

Comment: Why are you using a `FileReader` at all? Just `window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0])` should work…

Comment: If your backend server only supports text you will have to encode your array of bytes in a textual way E.G base64. so you read using ByteArray covert ByteArray to bas64 send it to your server check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9267899/arraybuffer-to-base64-encoded-string

Answer (score 3):

The [`readAsText` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsText) doesn't simply make the bytes accessible in a UCS-16 string. Instead, it *decodes them as text*, according to a given text encoding format, by default UTF-8. This will mess with any binary data that you are trying to read. As you already figured out, use `readAsArrayBuffer` for that.

You can try to use a `TextEncoder` to [`encode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextEncoder/encode) your text back to a typed array, but that's not guaranteed to yield the same result: a BOM gets stripped, invalid UTF-8 sequences lead to errors, and if you're unlucky then even Unicode normalisation will happen.

It might get easier if you explicitly specify a single-byte decoding, but really you should just use `readAsArrayBuffer`.

Comment: `readAsText` of binary data (like images) will corrupt the file. When decoding from UTF-8 there are byte-sequences that can be altered. Only values between 0x00 - 0x7F are copied verbatim. Values between 0xC2 to 0xDF indicates that it is a two byte sequence, 0xF0 to 0xFF that it is a four byte sequence. If the following bytes in the sequence isn't between 0x80 to 0xBF then the sequence is illegal an may be removed or altered. For example [0xF1,0x80,0x80,0x80] is decoded to [0x40000] and [0xF0,0x80,0x80,0x80] to [0xFFFD,0xFFFD,0xFFFD,0xFFFD] (where 0xFFFD is the Replacement Character)

Comment: @some Thanks for the example!

Comment: I forgot to convert 0x40000 to surrogate pairs. [0xF1,0x80,0x80,0x80] is decoded as [0xD8C0,0xDC00]. I added an answer with more examples.

Answer (score 2):

As [Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/) already have answered, you should use `readAsArrayBuffer` for binary data instead of `readAsText`, since the later decodes the byte sequences, by default as UTF-8.

UTF-8 is a variable length encoding, where a character can be between 1 and 4 bytes. Running the decoder on binary data that isn't UTF-8 will irrecoverable corrupt the binary data.

For example, only 0x00-0x7F is copied verbatim. 0xC2 to 0xDF is the start sequence of a 2 byte sequence, 0xE0 to 0xEF of a 3 byte sequence and 0xF0 to 0xFF of a 4 byte sequence. 0x80 to 0xBF is part of a sequence.

Here are a couple of examples of how it gets corrupted (node 12.1):

```
      ORIGINAL        =>  DECODED from UTF-8 to UCS-2  =>                 ENOCDED from UCS-2 to UTF-8
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[0xC2,0x80,0x80,0x80] => [0x0080,0xFFFD,0xFFFD]        => [0xC2,0x80,0xEF,0xBF,0xBD,0xEF,0xBF,0xBD]
[0xC3,0x80,0x80,0x80] => [0x00C0,0xFFFD,0xFFFD]        => [0xC3,0x80,0xEF,0xBF,0xBD,0xEF,0xBF,0xBD]
[0xE0,0x80,0x80,0x80] => [0xFFFD,0xFFFD,0xFFFD,0xFFFD] => [0xEF,0xBF,0xBD,0xEF,0xBF,0xBD,0xEF,0xBF,0xBD,0xEF,0xBF,0xBD]
[0xE1,0x80,0x80,0x80] => [0x1000,0xFFFD]               => [0xE1,0x80,0x80,0xEF,0xBF,0xBD]
[0xF0,0x80,0x80,0x80] => [0xFFFD,0xFFFD,0xFFFD,0xFFFD] => [0xEF,0xBF,0xBD,0xEF,0xBF,0xBD,0xEF,0xBF,0xBD,0xEF,0xBF,0xBD]
[0xF1,0x80,0x80,0x80] => [0xD8C0,0xDC00]               => [0xF1,0x80,0x80,0x80]
[0xF0,0x80,0x00,0x00] => [0xFFFD,0xFFFD,0x0000,0x0000] => [0xEF,0xBF,0xBD,0xEF,0xBF,0xBD,0x00,0x00]
[0x80,0x80,0x80,0x80] => [0xFFFD,0xFFFD,0xFFFD,0xFFFD] => [0xEF,0xBF,0xBD,0xEF,0xBF,0xBD,0xEF,0xBF,0xBD,0xEF,0xBF,0xBD]
[0x81,0x82,0x83,0x84] => [0xFFFD,0xFFFD,0xFFFD,0xFFFD] => [0xEF,0xBF,0xBD,0xEF,0xBF,0xBD,0xEF,0xBF,0xBD,0xEF,0xBF,0xBD]
```

0xFFFD is the *Replacement Character* that is used when the input can't be converted to a know codepoint.

Answer (score -1):

It could be what I ran into long ago working with graphic files.   Binary files are in specific format for a reason, and things like cr/lf might be legit in their own place.  By reading a binary file as text and writing it back out, could actually throw in extra cr/lf per line thus throwing off the original format/content/pointers in the file.

To confirm this, I would take your original file, read/write as array buffer to one Test file, then do the same thing with read/write as text to a SecondTest file.  Then do a binary compare between the two files.

I would bet you are getting extra stuff in there unintentionally.