# No Unicode CMAP Error importing custom font in JSPDF

Tags: javascript, fonts, pdf-generation, create-react-app, jspdf

I'm using [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF) and trying to import a custom font in my react single-page-app using create-react-app. I followed the steps [here](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF#use-of-utf-8--ttf) to create a js file with my font using the [jspdf font converter](https://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/fontconverter/fontconverter.html). I am importing my js file containing my font using the steps in Tunc's answer to [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57661092/jspdf-pubsub-error-no-unicode-cmap-for-font), but I'm still getting the following error message, "jsPDF PubSub Error No unicode cmap for font Error: No unicode cmap for font". The font file I'm using for the converter is the desktop font (tff format) from here: https://www.cufonfonts.com/font/wingdings

Here is my js file with my font:

```
import jsPDF from "jspdf"; //added to get rid of error message "jsPDF not defined" for my react SPA

(function(jsPDFAPI) {
var font = [I clipped the giant font text for this post];
var callAddFont = function() {
  this.addFileToVFS("wingdings-normal.ttf", font);
  this.addFont("wingdings-normal.ttf", "wingdings", "normal");
};
jsPDFAPI.events.push(["addFonts", callAddFont]);
})(jsPDF.API);
```

When I import the js font file in my react component `import "../wingdings-normal";` I get the "No unicode cmap for font" error message. Is the font cmap removed in the converter?

Comment: Wingdings likely is not a unicode font

Comment: @KevinBrown, thanks for your input. Do you have a recommendation for rendering a checked and unchecked checkbox as text? I found this page for dec & hex unicode equivalent for wingdings2 font but I haven't had any success adding this to my pdf as of yet: http://www.alanwood.net/demos/wingdings-2.html

Comment: Msgothic likely has the characters