# SCRIPT:28 out of stack space in IE11

Tags: javascript

I'm converting an image to `base-64` through

```
btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer)));
```

This line works perfectly in all the browser except **IE11**.

**IE11** throws an error if file size exceeds 1.5 MB.

Any workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

Got the workaround,

Anybody facing this issue can refer to Mobz answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9458996/2739391