# how to show image from bytes?

Tags: reactjs, api, axios, response-headers

I have an API which returns an Image as byte data, but I don't know how can I show this bytes in the src of the img tag

here is an example of what I got in the result
[image]

and this is how I use axios to make use of the API

```
const getFile = async (nombreArchivo) => { 
const tokenApp = window.localStorage.getItem('token')
const {data: res} = await axios.get(`${url}photo-2.jpg`,
{  headers: { Authorization: `${tokenApp}` },responseType: 'json',});
return res;};
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `{responseType: 'blob'}` to your axios config.

Then use `<img src={URL.createObjectURL(responseData)} />`to display it.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the `bytes` array into the `base64` encoding and use this for rendering the image.

`byte[]` to `base64`:

```
const base64String = btoa(String.fromCharCode(...new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer)));
```

source of the conversion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11562550/6608222)

Once you have the `base64` you can use it into the `src` field of a standard `img` tag