# Decrypt AES-256-CBC using openssl_decrypt in PHP from Subtle Crypto Javascript Payload

Tags: encryption, aes, php-openssl, webcrypto-api, subtlecrypto

I'm trying to *encrypt* something in JS using webcrypto/window.crypto to AES-256-CBC and trying to *decrypt* it using PHP's `openssl_decrypt` function.

My problem is that the decyrption function simply returns `false` and thus does not seem to work.

```js
const encoder = new TextEncoder();
const encoded = encoder.encode('Hello this is a test.');

const encryptionKey = await window.crypto.subtle.generateKey(
    {
        name: 'AES-CBC',
        length: 256,
    },
    true,
    ['encrypt', 'decrypt'],
);

const iv = window.crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(16));
const cipher = await window.crypto.subtle.encrypt(
    {
        name: 'AES-CBC',
        iv,
    },
    encryptionKey,
    encoded,
);


const exportedKey = await window.crypto.subtle.exportKey(
    'jwk',
    encryptionKey,
);

console.log(exportedKey.k); 

sendToBackend({
    cipher: btoa(new Uint8Array(cipher)), // "MTMsMjIzLDE5NSwxNzYsMjA0LDE5MSwxOTYsMjEyLDIwNCwyMzAsMjcsMSwxMjAsMTQzLDE2MSwxMTgsMTYwLDIzOSw4NywyMDksMjQ0LDIwNCwyMzgsODYsMTgzLDIyOCwxMzksMjIwLDcwLDY5LDI0OSwxODQ="
    iv: btoa(new Uint8Array(iv)), // "MTQ5LDE2Nyw4LDE2NywyMjAsMTA4LDEwMSw1Niw4Miw3MiwxMjAsMjM5LDE4NCw0OCwyNTIsMTE=",
    password: exportedKey.k, // "szq1aOg-F_72vWrdJatWyQp3iOXIus-cE19sO4bSOLs"
});
```

Now when I try to decrypt this in the backend using PHP, I get `false`:

```php
$key = "szq1aOg-F_72vWrdJatWyQp3iOXIus-cE19sO4bSOLs";
$payload = "MTMsMjIzLDE5NSwxNzYsMjA0LDE5MSwxOTYsMjEyLDIwNCwyMzAsMjcsMSwxMjAsMTQzLDE2MSwxMTgsMTYwLDIzOSw4NywyMDksMjQ0LDIwNCwyMzgsODYsMTgzLDIyOCwxMzksMjIwLDcwLDY5LDI0OSwxODQ=";
$iv = "MTQ5LDE2Nyw4LDE2NywyMjAsMTA4LDEwMSw1Niw4Miw3MiwxMjAsMjM5LDE4NCw0OCwyNTIsMTE=";
$dec = openssl_decrypt($payload, 'AES-256-GCM', $key, false, $iv);
var_dump($dec); // false
```

Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the JavaScript side, the Base64 encoding fails, as can be seen from the length of the result. In the following JavaScript code the function `ab2b64()` is used for this conversion:

```js
(async () => {

    const encoder = new TextEncoder();
    const encoded = encoder.encode('Hello this is a test.');

    const encryptionKey = await window.crypto.subtle.generateKey(
        {
            name: 'AES-CBC',
            length: 256,
        },
        true,
        ['encrypt', 'decrypt'],
    );

    const iv = window.crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(16));
    const cipher = await window.crypto.subtle.encrypt(
        {
            name: 'AES-CBC',
            iv,
        },
        encryptionKey,
        encoded,
    );

    const exportedKey = await window.crypto.subtle.exportKey(
        'jwk',
        encryptionKey,
    );

    console.log("key (Base64url): " + exportedKey.k)
    console.log("iv (Base64): " + ab2b64(iv))
    console.log("ciphertext (Base64): " + ab2b64(cipher))

    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/11562550/9014097
    function ab2b64(arrayBuffer) {
        return window.btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer)));
    }

})();
```

Possible output:

```
key (Base64url): 2TCb_J7EnsXgpYRhrJUG4ChgDNcnpcZ4sSCOK739U8A
iv (Base64): cWXBcXDyEcKTSRi2zPsqrg==
ciphertext (Base64): DRFokcfbdsfhNz/IeFUdmUQzxEAg09Y+gTE1DTfmzoA=
```

On the PHP side the wrong mode is used, i.e. GCM must be replaced by CBC for compatibility with the JavaScript code (although GCM would actually be the more secure choice).
Furthermore, the key must be Base64url (not Base64) decoded, while IV and ciphertext must be Base64 decoded. For the ciphertext an *implicit* Base64 decoding can be done by setting the 4th parameter of `openssl_decrypt()` to `0`:

```php
<?php
$keyB64url = "2TCb_J7EnsXgpYRhrJUG4ChgDNcnpcZ4sSCOK739U8A";
$keyB64 = str_replace(['-','_'], ['+','/'], $keyB64url );
$key = base64_decode($keyB64);
$iv = base64_decode("cWXBcXDyEcKTSRi2zPsqrg==");
$payload = "DRFokcfbdsfhNz/IeFUdmUQzxEAg09Y+gTE1DTfmzoA=";
$dec = openssl_decrypt($payload, 'AES-256-CBC', $key, 0, $iv);
var_dump($dec); // string(21) "Hello this is a test."
?>
```

---

**Edit:**

While CBC only provides confidentiality, [GCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Galois/counter_(GCM)) provides confidentiality and authenticity/integrity, making GCM more secure. Note that with CBC, a message authentication code (MAC) can be used so that (in addition to confidentiality) also authenticity is provided; however, the advantage of GCM is that this is done *implicitly*.

For GCM on the JavaScript side the algorithm in `generateKey()` and `encrypt()` must be changed from `AES-CBC` to `AES-GCM`. The recommended length of the nonce for GCM is 12 bytes (although other nonce lengths including 16 bytes are supported), which requires a corresponding change in `getRandomValues()`:

```js
(async () => {

    const encoder = new TextEncoder();
    const encoded = encoder.encode('Hello this is a test.');

    const encryptionKey = await window.crypto.subtle.generateKey(
        {
            name: 'AES-GCM',
            length: 256,
        },
        true,
        ['encrypt', 'decrypt'],
    );

    const iv = window.crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(12));
    const cipher = await window.crypto.subtle.encrypt(
        {
            name: 'AES-GCM',
            iv,
        },
        encryptionKey,
        encoded,
    );

    const exportedKey = await window.crypto.subtle.exportKey(
        'jwk',
        encryptionKey,
    );

    console.log("key (Base64url): " + exportedKey.k)
    console.log("iv (Base64): " + ab2b64(iv))
    console.log("ciphertext (Base64): " + ab2b64(cipher))

    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/11562550/9014097
    function ab2b64(arrayBuffer) {
        return window.btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer)));
    }

})();
```

A possible output is:

```
key (Base64url): jno7Ydkris18yDtJ2nvPeWBrdiPqmqoZheYcc0qpjO8
iv (Base64): zETSdleg3nYdTbDv
ciphertext (Base64): HiPRcKl3MhzG+U4gKnpnK44hl9jqIzunMd15WnM9l4XkCjylXg==
```

As mentioned above, GCM is an authenticated encryption mode and uses a tag for authentication. WebCrypto implicitly concatenates ciphertext and tag (16 bytes long by default) in this order, while PHP processes both separately. Therefore, ciphertext and tag must be separated on the PHP side:

```php
<?php
$keyB64url = "jno7Ydkris18yDtJ2nvPeWBrdiPqmqoZheYcc0qpjO8";
$keyB64 = str_replace(['-','_'], ['+','/'], $keyB64url );
$key = base64_decode($keyB64);
$iv = base64_decode("zETSdleg3nYdTbDv");
$payload = base64_decode("HiPRcKl3MhzG+U4gKnpnK44hl9jqIzunMd15WnM9l4XkCjylXg==");
$payloadLen = strlen($payload);
$ciphertext = substr($payload, 0, $payloadLen - 16);
$tag = substr($payload, $payloadLen - 16, 16);
$dec = openssl_decrypt($ciphertext, 'AES-256-GCM', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv, $tag);
var_dump($dec); // string(21) "Hello this is a test."
?>
```

Comment: Thank you, this works! I also understand that GCM is the better choice. Which changes need to be done to switch to GCM? The `iv` seems to require `Uint8Array(12)` instead of 16, apart from that I'm not sure.

Comment: @ffritz - See the edit section of my answer, please.

Comment: This was extremely helpful, thank you very very much for this comprehensive answer.