# Decoding and encoding Typed Array in JS giving different result than original value

Tags: javascript, encoding, decoding

Does anyone know why this happens

```js
    const encoder = new TextEncoder()
    const decoder = new TextDecoder()
    const array = new Uint8Array([200])
    console.log(encoder.encode(decoder.decode(array))) // prints [239, 191, 189]
```

As far as I know, decoding and encoding anything should give me the exact same value. Should not it just print [200] back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are decoding `[200]` which is an invalid UTF-8 sequence and results in `�`

```js
const decoder = new TextDecoder()
const array = new Uint8Array([200])
console.log(decoder.decode(array)) // prints �
```

Since the binary representation of `200` is `11001000`, the decoder thinks this is a two-byte UTF-8 character:

> In UTF-8 encoding, a byte starting with 110 indicates that it's the first byte of a two-byte encoded character.

Then when you try to encode � you just get the following output `[239, 191, 189]` or `0xEF 0xBF 0xBD` in hexadecimal

```js
const encoder = new TextEncoder()
const array = new Uint8Array([])
console.log(encoder.encode("�"))
```

Comment: oh nice! Thanks for the explanation! I want to store this array as string in redis, do you know what approach I should take then please

Comment: @bugwheels94 you should use `encoder.encode([200])` first, might be that you are running `decode` then `encode` vs. the other way around. If that doesn't work, what about just using `JSON.stringify`?

Comment: Hmm, in that case .toString() is also a more compact solution but I was looking for something compressed as TextDecoder cause .toString adds a comma in between values hence increasing a bit

Comment: @bugwheels94 edited my last comment, but I think the root of the issue is you are trying to `decode` before `encoding`, if you flip those it should be fine!

Comment: encoder then decoder is pretty smart. It is giving the output exactly like native .toString() though. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @bugwheels94 you want to encode this data in another format. The most common one for this task is base64. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9267899/arraybuffer-to-base64-encoded-string

Comment: @Kaiido yes base64 is also a great option. Though, I discovered that I can insert Typed array in redis directly by converting it to buffer. so solved using that. But thank you so much for advice!